# Merge existing records in neo4j, remove duplicates, keep relationships

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I've imported my millions of records using `CREATE` for performance reasons, now I want to `MERGE` the records together, and keep all the relationships intact.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
MATCH (c1:company), (c2:company) 
WITH c1, c2 
WHERE c1.name = c2.name 
SET c1=c2
```

Is the type of thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to merge nodes in cypher you can do something like this:

```
MATCH (c:Company)
WITH c.name as name, collect(c) as companies, count(*) as cnt
WHERE cnt > 1
WITH head(companies) as first, tail(companies) as rest
LIMIT 1000
UNWIND rest AS to_delete
MATCH (to_delete)<-[r:WORKS_AT]-(e:Employee)
MERGE (first)<-[:WORKS_AT]-(e)
DELETE r
DELETE to_delete
RETURN count(*);
```

see: http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?dropbox-14493611%2Fmerge_nodes.adoc

Comment: Brilliant, I like how you handle deleting the relationship and the use of collections.

Comment: Alas, this did not work as intended. It seemed to get rid of most of my 'companies' and create an eyeball graph.

Comment: Worked for me, performant too. Deleted 1074 nodes, deleted 11529 relationships, returned 1 row in 3540 ms from 350,000 nodes

Comment: How can I adapt this to handle merging nodes that can have between 0 and 2 optional relationships?  I have nodes of type A that have a single property on which I want to merge, and nodes of type B and C to/from which A may have relationships.  I know how to write my query up through the UNWIND, but I'm stuck on how to merge the optional relationships.

Comment: you just change the match to optional match for :A and add a second after for :B

Comment: Otherwise David perhaps ask a new question referring to this one.

Comment: @MichaelHunger , thanks, I've just posted a new question referencing this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274919/merge-existing-records-in-neo4j-remove-duplicates-keep-optional-relationships) if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way. There is no way to move relationships around, and no way to coalesce existing nodes. You should use MERGE from the beginning, along with constraints and indexes to aid performance.

Comment: Oh don't tell me that. :( These things take forever to MERGE.