# Merging duplicate nodes and their relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a requirements to merge the duplicate nodes and keep one copy. Issue I am facing is, when I merge nodes, there will be duplicate relationship created. Instead, I want to merge the relationship as well without duplicates.

Can you give some suggestions?

```
CREATE (n:People { name: 'Person1', lastname: 'Person1LastName', email_ID:'Person1@test2.com' })
CREATE (n:People { name: 'Person2', lastname: 'Person2LastName', email_ID:'Person2@test2.com' })
CREATE (n:People { name: 'Person2', lastname: 'Person2LastName', staysin:'California' })
CREATE (n:People { name: 'Person3', lastname: 'Person3LastName', email_ID:'Person3@test2.com' })

Person2  -[r:Has_Met]->(Person1)

(Person3)-[r:FRIENDS_WITH]->(Person2) having email_ID='Person2@test2.com'
```

Now i wants to keep Person2 nodes and keep both the relationship with other nodes - 
something like this:

```
MATCH (p:People{name:"person1"})
WITH p.name as name, collect(p) as nodes, count() as cnt
WHERE cnt > 1
WITH head(nodes) as first, tail(nodes) as rest
UNWIND rest AS to_delete
MATCH (to_delete)-[r:HAS_MET]->(e:name)
MERGE (first)-[r1:HAS_MET]->(e)
on create SET r1=r
SET to_delete.isDuplicate=true
RETURN count();
```

[This is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315926/), but here I know only one relationship (HAS_MET) will be considered. How do I consider all the relationships once?

Comment: What is your data model (including node labels, and relationship types)? Also, in your data, is it possible for 2 relationships (of the same type and directionality) between a pair of nodes to have different values for the same property? If so, do you care which value ends up being used in the merged relationship?

Comment: Or, do you only consider two relationships to be a duplicates if they have identical  type and properties?

Comment: i have 2 people nodes , having the has_met relationship. For example 
P1-[:HASMET] –P2
Duplicate P1-[:HASMET]-P2
Merge 2 Nodes People1 and Duplicate People 1, it gives People Node but it Creates 2 has MET relationship with P2 ,i wants to avoid 2nd HAS MET relationship while merging...

Comment: something like this , MATCH (p:People{name:"person1"})
WITH p.name as name, collect(p) as nodes, count(*) as cnt
WHERE cnt > 1
WITH head(nodes) as first, tail(nodes) as rest
UNWIND rest AS to_delete
MATCH (to_delete)-[r:HAS_MET]->(e:name)
MERGE (first)-[r1:HAS_MET]->(e)
on create SET r1=r
SET to_delete.isDuplicate=true
RETURN count(*);
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315926/merge-existing-records-in-neo4j-remove-duplicates-keep-relationships/25343219  . but here i know only one relationship(HAS_MET) will be consider, how do i consider all the relationship once.

Comment: Please update your question, above, with the additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without presentation of your model or listing of sample data, unfortunately, I am only able to answer in general, which may help you nevertheless.
Have a look at the [APOC library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index33.html) and consider the use of the procedures [Merge Nodes](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index33.html#_merge_nodes) and [Redirect Relationship To](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index33.html#_redirect_relationship_to). You will find explanatory images and Cypher statements there for each case.

---

## Extension after question update

### Initial situation

```
CREATE
  (p1:People {name: 'Person1', lastname: 'Person1LastName', email_ID: 'Person1@test2.com'}),
  (p2a:People {name: 'Person2', lastname: 'Person2LastName', email_ID: 'Person2@test2.com'}),
  (p2b:People {name: 'Person2', lastname: 'Person2LastName', staysin: 'California'}),
  (p3:People {name: 'Person3', lastname: 'Person3LastName', email_ID: 'Person3@test2.com'}),
  (p2a)-[:HAS_MET]->(p1),
  (p2b)-[:HAS_MET]->(p1),
  (p3)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(p2a);
```

[image: graph]

### Solution

```
MATCH (oneNode:People {email_ID: 'Person2@test2.com'}), (otherNode:People {staysin: 'California'})
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([oneNode, otherNode])
YIELD node
MATCH (node)-[relation:HAS_MET]->(:People)
WITH tail(collect(relation)) AS surplusRelations
UNWIND surplusRelations AS surplusRelation
DELETE surplusRelation;
```

- line 1: select both to be combined nodes
- line 2: call appropriate merge nodes procedure
- line 3: define result variable
- line 4: identify all relationships between the combined node and a met person (there are two at least)
- line 5: select all relationships but the first one
- line 7: delete all surplus relationships

### Result

- merged node Person2, containing all attributes from source nodes (note especially `email_ID` and `staysin`)
- one relationship Person1-Person2

[image: graph2]

Comment: CREATE (n:People { name: 'Person1', lastname: 'Person1LastName', email_ID:'Person1@test2.com' })
CREATE (n:People { name: 'Person2', lastname: 'Person2LastName', email_ID:'Person2@test2.com' })
CREATE (n:People { name: 'Person2', lastname: 'Person2LastName', staysin:'California' })

CREATE (n:People { name: 'Person3', lastname: 'Person3LastName', email_ID:'Person3@test2.com' })

Person2  -[r:Has_Met]->(Person1)

(Person3)-[r:FRIENDS_WITH]->(Person2) having email_ID='Person2@test2.com'

Now i wants to keep Person2 nodes and keep both the relationship with other nodes once.

Comment: I've extended my answer by a concrete solution.